# The behavior of the executable file differs from that of the live server

Tags: function, npm, liveserver

Hi i'm relatively new to coding, particularly in Electron. I've organized my project into different folders with various files. When I use a live server, everything functions correctly. However, upon starting the code with 'npm run start' a specific part fails to work properly. I'm attempting to change the color with a click using the function change_color(), but unfortunately, it's not working as intended.

```
# Karteikarten.html

function change_color() {  
  const karteikartenElement = document.querySelector('.Karteikarten');  
  karteikartenElement.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';  
}  

# Ergänzung.js  

<div class="Karteikarten" onclick="change_color()">  
         <p>Karteikarten</p>  
    </div>
```

**Folderstructure**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hckni.png)

I need an explanation:)